# systemctl echos prints interference from other unit

Tags: systemd, logs, services, journalctl, systemctl

I am working on a service which runs just fine. My poblem (or rather a mild annoyance) is that when I run `systemctl status foo.service` or `journalctl -u foo.service` I will occasionally see error messages of [pulseaudio].

The interfering entries look like this (with the first two lines in bold and the last line in bold red):

```
[pulseaudio] server-lookup.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[pulseaudio] main.c: Unable to contact D-Bus: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.NotSupported: Unable to autolaunch a dbus-daemon without a $DISPLAY for X11
[pulseaudio] bluez5-util.c: GetManagedObjects() failed: org.freedesktop.DBus.Error.AccessDenied: Rejected send message, 2 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.104" (uid=1006 pid=21503 comm="/usr/bin/pulseaudio --start --log-target=syslog " label="unconfined") interface="org.freedesktop.DBus.ObjectManager" member="GetManagedObjects" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="org.bluez" (bus)
```

My service has nothing to do with pulseaudio at all and is fairly self contained. I even tried to replicate this with a minimal example. I don't really care about the source of the error because this is a temporary development VM¹, but I am curious why I see the output of pulseaudio here?

---

¹ The VM runs Linux Mint 19 Tara and the Host is a Windows 10 Pro x64